# Media queries not working on iPad and iPhone

Tags: media-queries

I´m trying to set media querys for the ipad and for mobiles and I don´t know where I go wrong.

If I have the below iPad query at the top, then the iPad works, but in the iPhone it is displaying the iPad query?

and if I have the iPhone query before the iPad, then the iPhone works and not the iPad.

So whatever media query is first, thats the one working!?

```
default styling at the top...

@media only screen and (max-width : 768px) {
iPad styling goes here....
}

  @media only screen and (min-width : 320px) and (max-width:480px;){
iPhone styling goes here....
}
```

Any input appreciated, thanks!

I have this in the page that uses it, maybe I have to have it in a separate css file?
I have to test!
Update, no it didn´t matter!

Comment: Remove the `;` from `max-width:480px;`.

Comment: Thanks, shanethehat, I missed that, but it still isn´t working.

Comment: Try like `@media (max-width: 768px) { ... }` and `@media (min-width: 320px) and (max-width: 480px) { ... }`.

Comment: Thanks, it worked as it was, just that I had a media query in another file that I´d missed :-)